# May we annotate style for TargetApi in android

Tags: android, android-layout, styles

I am trying to define the style

```
<style name="robotoCondensed">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
```

but `fontFamily` is not available for `api 10`, which I am using. So is there a way to use annotation in a stylesheet? Such as maybe `@TargetAPI`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` definition to your top-level XML tag, and then just add `tools:targetApi="10"` to the item defining `fontFamily`.